# DataBase.Query: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, dynamic-soql, developer-console

I am trying to use Aggregate result and dynamic query. I have tried the below code and I did get 101 error. Please help me in optimizing this code to avoid hitting governor limits. The error is at line 6

[image]

Comment: Where do you intend to use this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get number of contacts per `Account`, you can use a sub-query:

```
for (Account record : [SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account])
    system.debug(record.Id + ' - ' + record.Contacts.size());
```

Or just loop through one aggregate query:

```
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
    SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id) records FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId
])
    system.debug(aggregate.get(AccountId) + ' - ' + aggregate.get('records'));
```

Comment: Hey @Adrian
My requirement is not exactly this. To keep it simple, I have used the above example. If I still have to modify my code to avoid limits how can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect anyone to be able to answer such a general question. If you narrow it down to something more specific, it might be possible to help you.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142084/optimizing-soql-query-outside-of-for-loop-batch-class

I have posted this question. Please check my exact scenario