# Optimizing SOQL query outside of for loop: Batch class

Tags: apex, soql, batch, governorlimits

In the below code, line 31(**AggregateResult results = database.query(str)**), I have used Database.query inside a for loop. If this causes governor limit issue in future, please help me in optimizing this.

```
global database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

   return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
    List<SummaryData__c> summaryDataToUpdate = new List<SummaryData__c>();   
    Map<Id, String> newMap = new Map<Id, String>();
    Map<Id, Decimal> mapCals = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
    List<summaryData__c> toUpdate = new List<summaryData__C>();
    for(SummaryData__c summaryData : (List<SummaryData__c>)scope)
    {

        String queryString = 'SELECT count() FROM ' + summaryData.ObjectName__c + ' WHERE ' + summaryData.WhereClause__c;
        newMap.put(summaryData.id,queryString);

    }
    for(Id id: newMap.keySet())
    {
      for(String str: newMap.Values() )
      {
        if(newmap.get(id) == str)
        {
          AggregateResult results = database.query(str);
          Decimal recordCount = (Decimal)results.get('result');
          mapCals.put(id,recordCount);
        }
      }
    }
    for(Id id: mapCals.keySet())
    {
      summaryData__c s = new summaryData__c();
      s.id = id;
      s.RecordCount__c = mapCals.get(id);
      s.LastRunTime__c = DateTime.Now();
      toUpdate.add(s);

    }
    if(!toUpdate.Isempty())
    {
      Update toUpdate;
    }

}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage sm = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] sendingTo = new String[]{'dburgess@sdimktg.com','sshah@sdimktg.com'};
    sm.setToAddresses(sendingTo);
    sm.setSubject('Record Count Job Execution');
    sm.setPlainTextBody('Job was executed');
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{sm});
}
```

Comment: I would be extremely wary of implementing an object to define the where clause and object name for a query in this way. You should probably just set the batch size to one with `Database.executeBatch(batchInstance, scopeSize)`.

Comment: So setting Database.executeBatch(batchInstance, 1) will avoid hitting any limits?
Also, can you advise me if I can optimize this in anyway instead of setting batch size as 1

Comment: Given that you are trying to perform a query for each record in the scope, it is extremely unwise to set any other batch size.

Comment: Thanks for that. But can I modify my code in anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are trying to perform one query for each record in your `scope`, it is extremely unwise to even attempt executing this batch for any scope size other than 1. I do not think you will be able to restructure your code to get around that critical bottleneck.

```
Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch(), /*scopeSize*/ 1);
```